# node.js sequelize associations, include on condition

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Is it possible to pass a condition in the include array of a findAll query?

For example I have UsersModel, PostsModel and UserVotesModel.

Users can vote on posts.

For the logged in user I want to query posts and include only the vote for the current user. I am not able to do this using Sequelize's include param. Sequelize joins posts and UserVotes on postId, but for this specific query I want to join on both postId and UserId.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked Sequelize source code. This is not possible!

Answer (score 3):

If you include a model with a where condition ( that will default require to true) but if you mark it as false to LEFT OUTER JOIN the association

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    user_id: current_user_id
  },
  include: [
  {
    model: UserVote,
    where: {
      'user_id':  current_user_id
    },
    required: false
  }]
})
```