# how to have multiple associations/conditions/includes in node.js sequelize on findAll

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, select, sequelize.js

I have a mysql DB that I am accessing through sequelize in node.js.

I want to join 3 tables.

The relationship is:

```
Person n : n Work (associated through PersonWork having foreign key for Person and Work)
Work n : n Book (associated through BookWork having foreign key for Book and Work)
```

I want to get Person, Work and Book joined.

Right now I am nesting 2 queries in node, but the results seem to be rather slow.

```
SQLPersonWork.findAll({ where: {}, include: [SQLWork, SQLPerson] }).success(function (sqlresult) {
    sqlresult.forEach(function ProcessPersonWorkResult(oneresult) {
        var work = oneresult.work;
        var name = oneresult.person.name;
        (function (work, name) {
            SQLBookWork.findAll({ where: { "work_id": work.id }, include: [SQLBook] }).success(function (sqlbookresult) {
                sqlbookresult.forEach(function ProcessBookResult(onebook) {
                    // process result I want to get
                });
            });
        })(work, name);
    });
```

You can see the double nested findAll().

Is there a way to combine this into 1 query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the only answer..

according to [NodeJS Sequelize and FindAll with Include and constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050248/nodejs-sequelize-and-findall-with-include-and-constraints) and [node.js sequelize associations, include on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865190/node-js-sequelize-associations-include-on-condition) this seems impossible without going to direct sql - though this kind of seems to defy the purpose of sequelize.

```
var qstring = "SELECT * FROM mydb.person p \
    join mydb.personrole pr on p.id = pr.person_id \
    join mydb.work w on w.id = pr.work_id \
    join mydb.bookwork bw on bw.work_id = w.id \
    join mydb.book b on b.id = bw.book_id;";
sequelize.query(qstring).success(function (result) {
    console.log(result.count);
    result.forEach(function ProcessRatingResult(oneresult) {
        console.log(oneresult);
    });
});
```

This runs considerably faster as well.